# Select grandchild from array knockout

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

I'm trying to select a grand child from an array in an array.

If it was c# I would have wrote something like below

```
SubSteps.Select(item => item.First(subitem => subitem == 1)).First();
```

I have a code that works, but I'm not sure it is the best way to do it:

```
ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.SubSteps(),
        function (item) {
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(item.SubSteps(),
                function (subItem) { return subItem.InternalName == localStorage.getItem('lastWizardPage'); });
        }).SubSteps(), function (item) {
            return item.InternalName == localStorage.getItem('lastWizardPage');
        })
```

Can someone point me to the best direction? Is there a method I can use that I've never heard of perhaps?

Comment: I *think* you can try [CodeReview SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) (read their FAQ first though).

Comment: Thank you. Did not know CodeReview existed. I've read the tour and posted the question there. What to do with this one?

Comment: Let it sit probably, I think. It may get closed, but that's ok I guess.

Comment: Knockout is not a query language. There's no reason why you should be using it to do this. Use the right tools for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have not figured the answer yet, you could try using LinqJS and do something like this.

```
      Enumerable.From(self.SubSteps())
      .First(function (item) { return item.First( function(subItem) { return subItem == 1 }) })
      .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm! I was worried it would break the chain of observable, but of course it did not!